# Which one is more appropriate to use: More or most?

Tags: grammar

Which is more appropriate to use more or most in the sentence: Some accounts claim that rattle snake was (more or most) poisonous than any other snake that lives on Earth.

Answer (score 1):

The 'most' is the superlative degree.

So it can't be used with 'than' which follows 'more' (the comparative degree).

Have a look at this:
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=most+poisonous+than%2C+more+poisonous+than&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmore%20poisonous%20than%3B%2Cc0.

It shows the only usage of 'more ... than'.

The sentence with 'most' can be like this:

"Some accounts claim that rattle snake was the most poisonous snake on Earth."

Answer (score 1):

Some accounts claim that the rattle snake is more venomous than any other snake that lives on Earth.

Some accounts claim that the rattle snake is the most venomous of any snake that lives on Earth.

Answer (score 0):

*The rattlesnake is more poisonous than most of the venomous snakes that slither on the face of our planet.*

Or, alternatively:

*The rattlesnake is considered to be the most poisonous snake on Earth.*

Then again:

*No other snake that is to be found within proximity of human habitats, is considered to be more poisonous than the rattlesnake save and except for the Black Mamba.*